# How to change the default help viewer to chrome for visual studio 2010 sp1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'd like to view the online msdn help with chrome when I press F1 in visual studio 2010sp1.

I set the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Help\v1.0 with HelpViewerProgId="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

But I always get an error page.

> **Unable to Service Request**

I guess the reason is that the chrome incorrectly encodes the url.

I tried with `HelpViewerProgId="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%1"` but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post - [How to change the default browser in Visual Studio programmatically with PowerShell and possibly poke yourself in the eye](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx) You could get a tip there how to do that in general for any files in IDE.

As for F1 and Help pages - please read this MSDN thread - [Cannot open Visual Studio 2010 Help Files in another browsers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vssetup/thread/30afe492-7173-4c03-a671-02484e3fc560)

Does it work for you?

Comment: I want to change the browser for help only, not the default browser of which is used for run the web application.

Comment: So if the options above are no what you want, the answer for your question will be THERE IS NO WAY TO DO THAT.

Comment: I followed the instructions from http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/news/overridingthedefaultviewer, only the path of chrome.exe changed

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution:

1. Set Chrome as the system default browser, so the help will be displayed in chrome
2. Install the WoVS Default Browser Switcher ( http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921 ), so when I press the "debug" button, IE is started instead of chrome.